# Meteor email: Connection not closed

Tags: meteor, exim

I am sending personalized Email notification to my users with Meteor.methods():

```js
Orders._collection.rawCollection()
      .distinct('user', { day: dayId })
      .then((result) => {
        let mailList = []
        User.find({ _id : { $in : result } }).forEach((user) => {
          mailList.push({ to: user.emails[0].address, room: user.profile.room });
        });
        console.log('setting mail queue...')
        mailList.forEach((user, index) => {
          let delay = 0;
          let time = delay + (index*200);
          console.log('queue set for user '+user.to+" for "+ time/1000 +' seconds')
          Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('sending mail to: ' + user.to);
            Email.send({
              to: 'user.to',
              from: "test@example.pl",
              subject: "test ",
              html: template,
            });
          }, time)
        })
      });
```

This example sends all messages, but if there are more than 10 messages then EXIM returns error that there are more than 10 emails in one SMTP connection, and mails are moved to queue to send after 30 minutes. This happens even with 2.5 minute delays after every mail.

Is there any way to close smtp connection with server after mail is sent?
mail url is: `smtp://localhost:25`.

Comment: Have you tried mailgun? Meteor's Email package is good for one offs and limited use, but Mailgun may be better for your use case.

Comment: can't really use external service for sending off data over intranet :(

Comment: Do you have EXIM installed on the same machine that runs this Meteor code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Email` package is based on `node4mailer` (small modification to `nodemailer` to run it on Node 4).

By default, [`Email` sets `pool=true`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/email/email.js#L42) for transport options. That means
that it will reuse opened connection until amount of sent messages reaches its limit, whereas `nodemailer` [default pool options have `maxMessages=100`](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/lib/smtp-pool/index.js#L47).

Thus, by modifying your `MAIL_URL`, you have 2 ways to solve your problem:

1. Pass `10` as `maxMessages` for `nodemailer` transport:

   `smtp://localhost:25/?maxMessages=10`
2. Disable pool (that will cause `nodemailer` to open a new connection for every email):

   `smtp://localhost:25/?pool=false`

**Useful link**: `nodemailer` documentation: [Pooled SMTP](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/pooled/)

Comment: Perfect answer!